# could not connect to extensions after I document.write my webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I found questions regarding "extension not able to connect in new tab",where the solution is to use chrome.tab module, but din't found anything like this:

I am stuck at this from many days, I will be glad if anyone could help me around.

I am using extensions for cross Domain calls, but my webpage can connect to the extension (I think content script) only when my page is a pure html page.If I change my page's content using:
    document.open();
    document.write(html);
    document.close();
(I did this keep the url of my webpage same when a user log in)

I cannot get any Response from extension.
Is there any solution which I am missing.

code for Reference:
**HTML where I replace page:**

```
PageLoader.prototype.loadHTML = function(html) {
    if (history.pushState) 
    try {window.history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);}
    catch (e) {};

    document.open();
    document.write(html);
    document.close();
};
```

**crossDomain Code**:
this is function which is called on click of some button

```
`window.addEventListener( "message", function(event) {
    if (event.source != window ) return;
     callback(event.data.text); 
  });

 window.postMessage( { type: "com_logincat_xhr_get", url: url }, "*");
```

`

This postMessage is done but did not get any response from **chrome extension's content_script.js** (only If I have used document.write in my webpage to replace the content).
**content_script.js** also contain eventListner for message.

```
window.addEventListener( "message", function(event)
 {
   /* It contains piece of code to send message (chrome.runtime.sendmessage) */
 };
```

I found at some places content_script.js attaches only at pageLoad and document.write might be replacing things, but I did not found any solution for this.

I think the code is correct as it works smoothly when page is a simple direct html.I don't know what wrong document.write do to my webpage 
I Hope It will help,

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can post a full code sample?

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply @MrSmith , I have added a sample of some code, I am sorry I cannot paste full code , as it contains a large number of files.so, I have pastec few which will give you the Idea.

Comment: Hey I found that using 
document.documentElement.innerHTML = html; (where html is the html of my new page)
instead of:  
document.write(html);
state object of the page remains same , so I can call my extension Now :) but because innerHTML does not let <scripts> tag execute, it through me to another problem, as half of the new page HTML does not work now :(

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is my solution to the above problem.

I found that content_script.js of Extensions attaches to DOM only at pageLoad.
and using **document.write('html')**
 I was modifying the DOM, which was creating Issue for the connection with content_script.js,
so I decided to use 
**document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;**

using this I got into another problem which was that scripts were not getting executed which were in var html.

for that I did this:

```
var scriptToInclude = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
 for (var n = 0; n < scriptToInclude.length; n++)
     eval(scriptToInclude[n].innerHTML);
```

and it worked :)